# ember-data error while loading route: TypeError {}

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I recently started to implement the ember data library into my project but now everything is broken, the google chrome console provides me with these errors:

```
- Error while loading route: TypeError {} 
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined 
- Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

The URL I'm trying to open is: /#/track/85

This is the relevant code:

```
Shoutzor = Ember.Application.create();
Shoutzor.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: '/api/emberstore',
    host: 'http://www.shoutzor.nl'
});

var attr = DS.attr,
    hasMany = DS.hasMany,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

Shoutzor.Track = DS.Model.extend({
    id: attr('number'),
    title: attr('string'),
    //length: attr('number'),
    //artist: hasMany('artist'),
    //album: hasMany('album'),

    /* Convert the length in seconds to a string like '01:55' */
    convertedLength: function() {
        var sec_num = parseInt(this.get('length'), 10); // don't forget the second parm
        var hours   = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
        var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
        var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

        if (hours   < 10 && hours > 0) {hours   = "0"+hours;}
        if (minutes < 10 && minutes > 0) {minutes = "0"+minutes;}
        if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0"+seconds;}
        var time    = ((hours != 0) ? hours + ':' : '') + ((minutes != 0) ? minutes +':' : '') + seconds;

        return time;
    }.property('length')
});

Shoutzor.Album = DS.Model.extend({
    id: attr('number'),
    artist: belongsTo('artist'),
    title: attr('string'),
    cover: attr('string')
});

Shoutzor.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
    id: attr('number'),
    name: attr('string'),
    profileimage: attr('string')
});

Shoutzor.Router.map(function() {
    //Track Page
    this.route("track", { path: "/track/:id" });
});

Shoutzor.TrackRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        controller.set('pageTitle', "Track");
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('TrackContent', { outlet: 'pageContent', into: 'application' });
    },

    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('track', params.id);
    }
});

Shoutzor.TrackController = Ember.Controller.extend();

Shoutzor.TrackView = Ember.View.extend();
```

My API provides a response like:

```
{"tracks":{"id":85,"title":"Untitled","file":{"filename":"Lines of Latitude - You want it (Free Download).mp3","filepath":"\/home\/vhosts\/domains\/shoutzor\/music\/Lines of Latitude - You want it (Free Download).mp3","crc":"51ca8346","length":262,"id3":[]},"artist":[],"album":[]}}
```

I have been looking at multiple SO posts and google search results but none of those solve my problem (or I'm looking for the wrong thing),

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include `id: DS.attr()` in your model class. Also, the response for a singular resource should have the root key `track` instead of `tracks`:

```
{"track":{"id":85,"title":"Untitled","file":{"filename":"Lines of Latitude - You want it (Free Download).mp3","filepath":"\/home\/vhosts\/domains\/shoutzor\/music\/Lines of Latitude - You want it (Free Download).mp3","crc":"51ca8346","length":262,"id3":[]},"artist":[],"album":[]}}`
```

Comment: that works :) thanks! Do you know by any chance how to make the RESTAdapter make the URL it requests end with a "/" ?

Comment: if you need to play around with the URL construction, try overriding RESTAdapter#buildURL

Comment: I have a followup question, hope you guys can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431300/ember-data-assertion-failed-cannot-call-get-with-query-on-an-undefined-object