# ember-data Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'query' on an undefined object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Solving my previous question ([ember-data error while loading route: TypeError {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426833/ember-data-error-while-loading-route-typeerror)) Turned up a new error, because I think this problem is not related to the previous question I decided to create a new question for it.

The error I'm getting now is:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://www.shoutzor.nl//api/emberstore/tracks/85/".
Assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'query' on an undefined object. ember.js:394
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__ember1382024509870_meta' of undefined
```

(note: the double slash after "www.shoutzor.nl" is not creating an issue, the JSON response is still correct)

**EDIT:** It seems the problem is originating from one of these pieces of code because When I remove all Search-related code from the website it all works again (also I should note it does work when I visit a url like '/#/search/something' before anything else):

```
Shoutzor = Ember.Application.create();

Shoutzor.Router.map(function() {
    //Home Page
    this.route("home", { path: "/" });

    //Track Page
    this.route("track", { path: "/track/:id" });

    //Search page
    this.route("search", { path: "/search" });
    this.route("search", { path: "/search/:query" });
});

Shoutzor.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
       controller.set('pageTitle', "Search");
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('SearchPageContent', { outlet: 'pageContent', into: 'application' });
    }
});

Shoutzor.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    search: '',

    actions: {
        query: function() {
            //the current value of the text field
            var query = this.get('search');
            this.transitionToRoute('search', { query: query });
        }
    }
});

Shoutzor.SearchController = Ember.Controller.extend();
```

and my HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="SearchPageContent">
    {literal}
        <h1>Searching for: "{{search}}"</h1>
        {{input type="text" value="search" action="query"}}
    {/literal}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Map was causing the issue,

changing

```
this.route("search", { path: "/search" });
this.route("search", { path: "/search/:query" });
```

into

```
this.resource("search", { path: "/search" }, function() {
    this.route(':query');
});
```

solved my problem